# LEGO clone identification with letter B on studs

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands, 3rd-party

[image]

What LEGO clone is this?

It looks like LEGO, but I can't seem to find anything more.

Could you please help identifying this?

Comment: Is this a lego clone brick? Do you have more pictures of other parts? Also, I'm not sure I understand the sentence in the question regarding fabric. Is there a reason you suspect this has something to do with fabric?

Comment: I think this might be a bad translation from a non-native english speaker. "Fabric" could have been "Material" or even "sample" or "item". Especially the Fabric<->Material crossover is one that could easily be made by a Germanic language speaker.

Comment: Interestingly, Bayer used to produce test bricks on behalf of LEGO, and some of these had a B on their studs (apparently different letters indicated different stickiness or 'clutch' between bricks). That said, I don't *think* this is a Bayer brick.

Comment: @PhilB.: On the other hand, the German word "Fabrikat" means "brand"/"make", which can easily be mixed up with "fabric", as well.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything with Google in any reasonable amount of time, but here are some things it *isn't:*

- BanBao
- Best-Lock
- Cobi
- K'nex
- Kre-O
- Lite Brix
- Mega Bloks
- Tyco Super Blocks
- Sluban
- Wange
- NanoBlocks
- PlayMobil
- Star Diamond

Other than super obscure Chinese LEGO direct-steals, there aren't really any others.

But here is a legitimimate idea nowadays: They're printed. Face it, the top of each brick *definitely* has the trademark plastic lines of an untreated 3D -printer job. People are printing and/or selling bricks all the time these days!

And if you love them *that* much, you could have somebody make some for you!

Comment: Isn't the top of the brick **too** uniform and shiny for a 3D-printed brick?

Comment: @MarkStewart Not with standard acid treatment.